# Can't append to SVG Circle element

Tags: jquery, dom, svg, jquery-svg

I've looked at dozens of similar topics but none seem to work! My eyes are bleeding!

This is slightly unique. I'm using Morris.js to create a line graph. It outputs an SVG and then a bunch of circle elements. All I want to do is append my own tooltip to the circles (I don't want to use theirs.) But the tooltip doesn't append, or insert before, or prepend. I read because SVG isn't recognized as HTML in the DOM. I do have jquery.svg.js loaded.

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#firstTooltip').appendTo('<circle />');
});
```

html

```
<div id="tooltips" class="center">
<div id="firstTooltip" class="tooltip fs">Last Intake</div>
<div id="lineGraph" class="center ptm"></div>
</div>
```

The lineGraph div is what the Morris.js data feeds into and populates the SVG into.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dQLeL/ Here, it's appended to every <circle> element, but I still don't know how you'll use this :)

Comment: That didn't append to anything @MiljanPuzović

Comment: Yes it is, check in inspector.

Comment: It looks like its there but why does it not display?

Comment: In that case, just use .before() instead of .append() http://jsfiddle.net/dQLeL/1/

Comment: Maybe because <div> is not valid svg element

Comment: Any idea how to make it work? How do I make a foreignObject work?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues.

First, you're appending to a newly created circle:

```
$('#firstTooltip').appendTo('<circle />');
```

Should be

```
$('#firstTooltip').appendTo('circle');
```

To append to all circles.  The appendTo examples on the [**jQuery documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) should have told you this.

But this isn't valid either, because the SVG is implemented as XML embedded in an XHTML document.  You'll notice a root element in the SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" ...>
```

The SVG has its own XML NameSpace.  Which has it's own specifications on how to render its content, as described in the link.

That is why things like  will not render as they are not part of the rules.

Going back to your code...

You're trying to render the tooltip in the wrong place.  If you're using Chrome, Firefox, or Safari - there is a very useful "inspect" tool you should get used to using.  This would tell you that the tooltip is rendered outside of the SVG, and dynamically changed.

Furthermore, **[exploring the documentation](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html)**, which you should have checked before coming here to StackOverflow, you'd find a **hoverCallback** option.  And the **Labels** option.  Giving you the ability to customize the tooltip through the library, instead of trying to hack it.

Here's an example demonstrating both, to whichever fits your needs:
http://jsfiddle.net/rZPX5/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply. This works for the first label but what about the last label. Also I researched this method enough to know that the labels are all the same, just being updated with new info. So to have two labels active and visbile without hover is not possible without some serious hacking. I just needed a very simple static way to have a label at the begnning of the graph and one at the end that will ALWAYS stay above those points no matter what changes on the graph.

Comment: this would be an easy thing to implement if you forked the Morris.js github project and made your own updates.  You could include an option "alwaysShow:true".

if you want to hack it.  just create two divs and position them correctly... hint: $('circle:first').position()